# TypeError: Cannot destructure property `db` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typeerror, var, destructuring

I am getting a TypeError in my variable assignment for mongodb connection. Is there a workaround for this?

```
//server.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');

var { db: {user,pass,host,port,name } } = config;

var connectionString = `mongodb://${user}:${pass}@${host}:${port}/${name}`;

mongoose.connect(connectionString, { useMongoClient: true });
```

Error

```
C:\mean\webguidv1\server.js:65
  db: {
  ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `db` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Here is my config.js file

```
// config.js
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV; // 'dev' or 'test'

var dev = { app: { port: 3000 }, db: {user: '', pass: '', host: '', port: , name: '' }};

var test = { app: { port: 3000 }, db: {user: '', pass: '', host: '', port: , name: '' }};

var config = { dev, test };

module.exports = config[env];
```

Comment: please add `./config.js` file export

Comment: config is either undefined or null. The error is clear.

Comment: @Moti Korets I just added my config.js file to the post. Am I missing anything in this file?

Comment: run `console.log(env)` just before export make sure it is correct.

Comment: I tried console.log(env). I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to deconstruct `config` where `config` is `undefined` or `null`. In this case, I'm thinking it's `undefined`.

If you `console.log(require('./config'))`, you'll probably get `undefined`.

This error also appears if you try to deconstruct an object in function args in Node 10.7.0.

Comment: then what is the solution for this?

Comment: Make sure your imported file exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the json format by using bodyParser in that,

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: It has nothing to do with this, its not a request

Comment: It's not for this problem, I am experienced the same error and I missed to code the bodyparser